# VueJs Like Button Liked all the posts

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am using VueJs in Laravel actually I made a VueJS component which contains like button and attached it with the loop so it appears at the end of every post when I pressed any of like button it likes all the post
My VueJS is

```
Vue.component('like-button', {
    props: ['userId', 'likes'],

    data: function() {
        return{
            status: this.likes,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        likeButton(){
            axios.post('/like/' + this.userId)
                .then(response=>{
                    this.status = !this.status;
                    history.go(0);
                })
                .catch(errors =>{
                    if(errors.response.status === 401){
                        window.location = "/login";
                    }
                })
        }
    },
    computed: {
        /**
         * @return {string}
         */
        Texts() {
            return (this.status) ? 'UNLIKE' : 'LIKE';
        }
    },
    template: '<button v-on:click="likeButton" class="btn" style=" width: 100%; 
    background-color: #1b1e21;color: white; border: none;"
    v-text="Texts"></button> '

})
```

My blade Component is (Note: I am using the loop on that button so its appearance at the bottom of every post)

`<like-button user-id="{{ $user->id }}" likes="{{ $likes }}"></like-button>`

I want to like only that post whose button like button I Pressed

Comment: You need to store each like based on a) userId, b) postId. - `'/like/' + this.userId` clearly doesn't distinguish between posts, so how is the app supposed to know which post was liked?

Comment: then what should i write instead if '/like/' + this.userId
kindly guide a little bit

Comment: Well, probably something like `'/like/' + this.userId + '/' + this.postId`; but that's not enough obviously, you need a controller that stores the likes accordingly, you need a database table that stores `id - userId - postId` for each like, and you need to run respective SELECT queries to read how many users liked a post, etc.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisG your suggestion helps alot

Answer (score 0):

Acctually the mistake was at `'/like/' + this.userId`
I am taking userId instead of Post Id
Thanks to @ChrisG for help